# Fire back an event from modal window

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a table > tr (with a unique ID) > td (contains an number as HTML) > td (contains an image with class=”delete” > img
A jQuery script targets the image and fires a request, updating a file (by deleting the line with the TR ID and the number in the TD).
Upon success, it changes the image from “ON” to “OFF” via attribute src.

That works. No problem.

My script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(‘table td img.delete’).click(function(){

$.get(“deleteRow.php”, {id: $(this).parent().parent().attr(‘id’)} );
$(this).attr(“src”, “img/code_off.gif”);

});
});
```

Then, I added a modal window (using Zebra Dialog).
Now, my problem is:

When I click on the “delete” image, it fires zebra_dialog. Fine.
I can get the ID of the TR.
But in no way I can update the image src ! :(

My code (I'm pretty new at this I must admit, so it might be wrong or uncorrectly written...) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(‘table td img.delete’).bind(‘click’, function(e) {

var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr(‘id’);

e.preventDefault();
$.Zebra_Dialog(‘my question ?’, {
‘type’: ‘question’,
‘title’: ‘my title’,
‘buttons’: [
{caption: 'YES', callback: function() { /* ??????? THERE SHOULD BE THE EVENT FIRED, therefore the IMG shall be updated, which is not, and I can't get it to work... I've been working around this : $('#'+id+'', 'this').attr("src", "img/code_off.gif") } */ }},
{caption: 'NO', callback: function() { alert('num : '+id+''); /* HERE, WE DO NOTHING, so just checking the ID, which is OK, then modal self-closes. */ }}
]
});
});

});
```

Anyone with a hint or a solution please ? Thanks ;)

Comment: Have you left out the code for the handler of the 'YES' button? If you are using 'this' in this handler, as you are in the first example shown, that is likely to be your problem.

Comment: As you mention it, I've tried and used 'this' for no result :)
This was what I was working around :
$('#'+id+'', 'this').attr("src", "img/code_off.gif") }
But I have no idea of what I can do...

Comment: found it ! FYI :

var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr(‘id’);
var imgrow = $(this); /* there you get the right parent */
...
in the callback => imgrow.attr("src", "img/code_off.gif");